# Turn off Focus assist via GPO not working as expected

Tags: windows, powershell, group-policy, windows-update, sccm

Is there a standardized way to turn off focus assist centrally since i am trying to display balloon tips and toast notifications for applications and windows updates being deployed from sccm software center on the clients. My attempt to disable it via this policy setting Go to the following path:
User configuration > Administrative Templates > Start Menu and Taskbar > Notifications > Turn off Quiet Hours Policy > set to enable didnt work as expected, it either remained at "priorty only" or "alarms only" after i restart the system. Maybe there is another way via registry or script to handle this?